# Links to open in Safari browser, using Phonegap 3.3

Tags: javascript, html, css, cordova, phonegap-build

I've built an app using purely HTML, CSS and JS within Phonegap Build 3.3. I want to include a number of links to websites, that I'd like to open in Safari rather than the in-app browser. Can anyone shed some light? I've tried all of the obvious JS using _system as the target etc.

Config.xml is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<widget 
    xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets"
    xmlns:gap   = "http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    version     = "1.1.0">

    <preference name="orientation" value="portrait"/>
    <preference name="target-device" value="universal"/>
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="false"/>
    <preference name="disable-cursor" value="true"/>
    <preference name="android-installLocation" value="auto"/>
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true"/>
    <preference name="webviewbounce" value="false"/>

    <gap:config-file platform="ios" parent="UISupportedInterfaceOrientations" overwrite="true">
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeOmg</string>
    </array>
    </gap:config-file>

    <access origin="*" browserOnly="true" />

    <preference name="permissions" value="none"/>

    <gap:splash src="splash.png" />

    <icon src="Icon.png" gap:platform="ios" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="Icon-72.png" gap:platform="ios" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="Icon@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="Icon-72@2x.png" gap:platform="ios" width="144" height="144" />

    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_at_2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default_iphone5.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <gap:splash src="splash/ios/Default-Portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />

</widget>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You still need to use the InAppBrowser plugin but configure it this way in config.xml:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser" />
<feature name="InAppBrowser">
    <param name="ios-package" value="CDVInAppBrowser" />
</feature>
<preference name="stay-in-webview" value="false" />
```

Then in your js code:

```
window.open(url, "_system");
```

See here for the [InAppBrowser documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html).

Comment: Thanks for this, I've added this to the files and the plugin is definitely installed, however it still opens in the InAppBrowser! Any ideas?